# Undefined name 'AuthException'. Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am getting error like

> Undefined name 'AuthException'

When I am trying to use it as following in my Flutter app.

```
  Future<bool> login({phoneNr, BuildContext context}) async {
    _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNr,
      timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
      verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential credential) async {
        UserCredential result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        User user = result.user;
        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id, arguments: user);
        }
      },
    verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) // THIS LINE HERE
    );
  }
```

I know, they might have changed the name just like they did for "FirebaseUser" to just "User"; but their formal documentation still shows "AuthException" as a valid class. However despite importing and upgrading all expected packages, I am still getting the same error. Any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the current [api docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth_platform_interface/latest/firebase_auth_platform_interface/PhoneVerificationFailed.html), you should use `FirebaseAuthException` instead.

You can as well remove the type and have it inferred:
`verificationFailed: (exception) {}`

Comment: Have tried this and several others. Don't work. The documentation is referring to `AuthException` while in lib code I saw both. Confusing ah!

Comment: What version of firebase_auth are you using?

Comment: firebase_auth: ^0.18.1+2

Comment: Try removing the type and have `verificationFailed: (exception)`

Comment: @Akroa : Yes it worked! Stupid of me to use a type for a void function. Thanks. Please post it as answer.

Comment: Edited and added it to the answer

Answer (score -1):

Use FirebaseAuthException instead of AuthException if you are using Flutter 2.